# Connecting/disconnecting to COM port expect

Tags: tcl, expect, kill, spawn

Can't seem to disconnect properly from the com port in use and end the spawned process. I need to disconnect from the COM port, then reconnect.

```
# Read the COM port from the command line
if { $argc >= 1 } {

   set file [lindex $::argv 0]
} else {

    set file /dev/ttyUSB0
}

set fh [open $file RDWR]

fconfigure $fh -mode "115200,n,8,1" -blocking 0 -buffering none -eofchar {}
spawn -open $fh -noecho
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using "source" to run my other tcl scripts when I should have been using exec. Now I can allow my device to shut off, then turn back on and communicate again.

Answer (score 0):

To disconnect from the serial port, you've got to close the channel (because that translates into a close on the underlying OS file descriptor). Because you've attached it to an expect spawn_id (the result of the `spawn`) you have to close that. You do that with:

```
close -i $spawn_id
```

Though if you only have one thing spawned at a time, you can just:

```
close
```

You'll have to go through the whole process (`open`, `fconfigure` and optionally `spawn -open`) again to reconnect. You might want to refactor that out into a procedure…

Comment: I've used this, but it still has trouble reconnecting. It will say that it cannot find com#. The purpose of the script is so that I can connect to the device, communicate, allow the device to shut off, disconnect from com port, and then reconnect and communicate once again.

Comment: I think what may be occurring is that I have used "source" to "run" my scripts that communicate with the device when I should have used exec. This may be where the problem is occurring.